# React JSX - Babel Transpilation - How does it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm starting with React and have some experience with ES6, and am trying to wrap my head around a basic component definition, that I found at [react-redux-starterkit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/src/routes/Counter/components/Counter.js)

```
export const Counter = (props) => (
  <div style={{ margin: '0 auto' }} >
    <h2>Counter: {props.counter}</h2>
    <button className='btn btn-default' onClick={props.increment}>
      Increment
    </button>
    {' '}
    <button className='btn btn-default' onClick={props.doubleAsync}>
      Double (Async)
    </button>
  </div>
)

export default Counter
```

When I ran it through Babel's [online transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2017%2Clatest%2Creact&code=import%20React%20from%20'react'%0A%0Aexport%20const%20Counter%20%3D%20(props)%20%3D%3E%20(%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20style%3D%7B%7B%20margin%3A%20'0%20auto'%20%7D%7D%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch2%3ECounter%3A%20%7Bprops.counter%7D%3C%2Fh2%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20className%3D'btn%20btn-default'%20onClick%3D%7Bprops.increment%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Increment%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%7B'%20'%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20className%3D'btn%20btn-default'%20onClick%3D%7Bprops.doubleAsync%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Double%20(Async)%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A)%0A%0Aexport%20default%20Counter%0A), I found that this transpiled to:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var Counter = exports.Counter = function Counter(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    { style: { margin: '0 auto' } },
    React.createElement(
      'h2',
      null,
      'Counter: ',
      props.counter
    ),
    React.createElement(
      'button',
      { className: 'btn btn-default', onClick: props.increment },
      'Increment'
    ),
    ' ',
    React.createElement(
      'button',
      { className: 'btn btn-default', onClick: props.doubleAsync },
      'Double (Async)'
    )
  );
};

exports.default = Counter;
```

Clearly, this has transpiled because I had checked the **react** option.

But I am having some trouble understanding the syntax. For instance, I see that first there is an `export const Counter` statement, which clearly exports a constant named `Counter` that is a function. I am presuming that it is a constant because the nothing in the class should be able to change it in the future.

But at the end, there is also a `export default Counter`, which is what is exported when the file is imported into another.

What I don't understand is, how does the `React.createElement` come in here? I haven't even imported React in this file. I don't see the normal JSX class based syntax that I see in most tutorials. Is this just how JSX is transpiled on Babel? Apologies for the rookie question.

Comment: You can just type some JSX code into https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=&playground=false and see what it is converted to. But the answer is yes, that's what JSX is converted to.

Answer (score 2):

> "Is this just how JSX is transpiled on Babel"

Yes. In React, JSX is used as a declarative form of "call `React.createElement` with these components and props."

That's why React files that use JSX fail to compile if you forget to `import React from "react"`, even where you don't explicitly reference `React`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you maybe explain a little further? ELI'm an AngularJS Dev?